# Fetch data on different server with backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I can't see what the problem with this is.

I'm trying to fetch data on a different server, the url within the collection is correct but returns a 404 error.  When trying to fetch the data the error function is triggered and no data is returned.  The php script that returns the data works and gives me the output as expected.  Can anyone see what's wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance :)

```
// function within view to fetch data

fetchData: function()
{
    console.log('fetchData')
    // Assign scope.
    var $this = this;
    // Set the colletion.

    this.collection = new BookmarkCollection();
    console.log(this.collection)
    // Call server to get data.
    this.collection.fetch(
    {
        cache: false,
        success: function(collection, response)
        {
            console.log(collection)
            // If there are no errors.
            if (!collection.errors)
            {

                // Set JSON of collection to global variable.
                app.userBookmarks = collection.toJSON();

               // $this.loaded=true;
                // Call function to render view.
                $this.render();

            }
            // END if.
        },
        error: function(collection, response)
        {
            console.log('fetchData error')
            console.log(collection)
            console.log(response)
        }
    });
},

// end of function
```

Model and collection:

```
BookmarkModel = Backbone.Model.extend(
{
    idAttribute: 'lineNavRef'
});

BookmarkCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend(
{
    model: BookmarkModel,

    //urlRoot: 'data/getBookmarks.php',
    urlRoot: 'http://' + app.Domain + ':' + app.serverPort + '/data/getBookmarks.php?fromCrm=true',

    url: function()
    {
        console.log(this.urlRoot)
        return this.urlRoot;
    },  

    parse: function (data, xhr)
    {
        console.log(data)
        // Default error status.
        this.errors = false;

        if (data.responseCode < 1 || data.errorCode < 1)
        {            
            this.errors = true;
        }

        return data;
    }       
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a cross domain request - no can do.  Will need to use a local script and use curl to access the one on the other domain.

Comment: Despite the fact you can't do the cross domain request with your AJAX call, it does not mean it cannot be done through other techniques. You can use JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the requests using JSONP (read about here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

To achive it using Backbone, simply do this:

```
 var collection = new MyCollection();

 collection.fetch({ dataType: 'jsonp' });
```

You backend must ready to do this. The server will receive a callback name generated by jQuery, passed on the query string. So the server must respond:

```
 name_of_callback_fuction_generated({ YOUR DATA HERE });
```

Hope I've helped.